# New sticky vote feature doesn't work on directly-linked answers

Tags: bug, voting, widgets

I love the new `js-vote-sticky` feature that lets the question's and answer's votes stick to the top of the window while scrolling, but it doesn't happen with answers that are directly linked. For instance, clicking [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c/14970830#14970830) will bring you to an answer to a long question, where the question's votes and the votes of all answers **except** the one linked will stick to the top of the window while scrolling.

Comment: I can't reproduce this currently; the linked post's votes are scrolling just fine. Not sure whether that's due to a pending [status-completed]...

Comment: @Air interesting... the issue still happens on my machine. What's a `status-completed`?

Comment: [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/info) is the tag that is applied by a mod/developer after a bug is fixed or a feature is implemented.

Comment: Closing this instead of retagging as [tag:support] because the sticky vote controls feature [has been removed again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am almost certain that the reason for this is that you've linked to one of your own posts. You can't vote for your own posts, and it could be argued that there's no reason to apply this feature to a post that you can't vote for.

Try following [this link to a different answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/615740/2359271). The feature will still be enabled for the linked answer and not for your own.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, that wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: It appears they still move down for my questions, though. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655389/is-bitset-worth-using

Comment: I'm no longer seeing any vote button movement, which suggests that new A/B groups selected to test updated behavior. I definitely did not see vote button movement on my questions originally.