# Why don't vote buttons move for locked or your own posts?

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, vote-count, widgets

There is currently [a feature in A/B testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254795/206222) causing vote buttons to move as you scroll up or down.

I have also noticed, ([mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257923/284991)) that the voting buttons won't work if the post is your own, or if the post is locked. However, on these posts, the feature causing vote buttons to move isn't enabled.

I understand that I can't vote on those kind of posts, but:

- The buttons are there to have a consistent look and feel, so the buttons should also be moved to have a consistent behavior.
- Even one can't vote, [established users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) could want to see vote counts in the middle of the post, with the benefit of the new feature.
- I guess that probably it will be easier to maintain the code, since there wouldn't be any logic to apply or not the new feature.

Is there a clear reason to disable that feature that I'm missing here?
Otherwise, why does the new feature of moving voting buttons not work for our own or locked posts?